# How do I determine the current timezone a machine is set to with Perl?

Tags: perl

I had assumed it would be as simple as `$ENV{TZ}`, but the `TZ` environment variable is not set, and yet the `date` command still knows I am in EDT, so there must be some other way of determining timezone (other than saying `chomp(my $tz = qx/date +%Z/);`).

Comment: Just for extra info, on my system, timezone is regulated by the file /etc/localtime and libc appears to know how to use that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
use POSIX;
print strftime("%Z", localtime()), "\n";
```

Comment: I thought about %Z, but I remember something about it not working on some systems.

Comment: According to man strftime, %Z is a standard specification and should be supported on all platforms.

Comment: I think I was remembering this from the POSIX docs: The "Z" specifier is notoriously unportable since the names of timezones are non‐standard. Sticking to the numeric specifiers is the safest route.  But I think this is probably safe enough for my purposes.

Comment: May be better to write `use POSIX qw( strftime );` Saves about 5ms and reduces the risk of name collision from loading additional constants.

Answer (score 7):

If you want something more portable than `POSIX` (but probably much slower) you can use DateTime::TimeZone for this:

```
use DateTime::TimeZone;

print DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'local' )->name();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
use POSIX;
localtime();
my ($std, $dst) = POSIX::tzname();
```

`tzname()` gives you access to the POSIX global `tzname` - but you need to have called `localtime()` for it to be set in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need something like `+05:30` (UTC+5.5/India time), you may use the following code.

```
my @lt = localtime();
my @gt = gmtime();

my $hour_diff = $lt[2] - $gt[2];
my $min_diff  = $lt[1] - $gt[1];

my $total_diff = $hour_diff * 60 + $min_diff;
my $hour = int($total_diff / 60);
my $min = abs($total_diff - $hour * 60);

print sprintf("%+03d:%02d", $hour, $min);
```

This answer is inspired by Pavel's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this faster:

```
my @lt = localtime(12*60*60);
my @gt = gmtime(12*60*60);
$tz = @lt[2] - @gt[2];
$tz_ = sprintf("%+03d:00", $tz); # for +02:00 format
```

Comment: To complement your answer you can use [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29400576/edit) button.

Answer (score -1):

Use: returns server time zone offset from UTC in hours.
This builds on the above examples and will work with DST

```
 my $hour_seconds = 60 * 60;
 my $day_seconds = 24 * $hour_seconds;
 #what is today's time at 00:00
 my $right_now = time();
 my $days = $right_now / $day_seconds;
 my $years = $right_now / ($day_seconds * 365);
 my $days_rounded = sprintf("%d", $days);
 my $today_seconds_at_midnight = $days_rounded  * $day_seconds;
 
 my @lt = localtime($today_seconds_at_midnight + ($day_seconds / 2)); #must use noon today or we will get odd values
 my $tz = $lt[2] - 12; #calc timezome difference, includes DST
```